# How can I use maven to include classes from a sibling module in a jar?

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, war

I have Maven project with a parent module and two children: `Service` and `API`.  The `Service` module is a WAR and contains all of the source files for the project, while the `API` module exists purely to build a jar containing a subset of classes from the Service module, and to deploy that jar to a local maven repo.

I've tried a combo of the `maven-dependency-plugin` and the `maven-assembly-plugin` to copy over the `Service` war and include it in the deployed `API` JAR, but I'm struggling to find a way to pull in just a specific set of classes from the Service module without roping in the entire fat WAR.

From `API`'s pom.xml:

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <excludeGroupIds>...</excludeGroupIds>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>package</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I've thought about building the slim JAR using the `maven-jar-plugin` from the `Service` module's pom, but this seems like bad practice.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather take out the implementation details from the `war` and put in a separate module.

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── service-api
|   ├── pom.xml
|   └── src
|       └── main
|           └── java
|               └── com
|                   └── stackoverflow
|                       └── SomeDao.java
├── service-impl
|   ├── pom.xml
|   └── src
|       └── main
|           └── java
|               └── com
|                   └── stackoverflow
|                       └── SomeDaoImpl.java
└── service-web
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src
        └── main
            └── webapp
                └── WEB-INF
                    └── web.xml
```

Let `service-impl` depend on `service-api`. And `service-web` will depend on the `service-impl`.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that your `API` project actually contain the classes that you want to deploy, and the `Service` module depend on it. If you want to modularize your project (and you should), do it the way Maven wants, and not trying to hack apart a single codebase.

Comment: That was my initial inclination, but I just wasn't entirely fond of letting the build system dictate how the codebase is structured, so I was searching for other potential avenues.  I too do agree that the way I was attempting to go about it was rather horrid.

Thanks!

Comment: @RustyBuckets - think of it not as the build system defining your project structure, but as a general modularization that enables reuse and creates clear lines of dependency. BTW, I think that *maba* has a better breakdown (and diagrams!) than I do.

Comment: @parsifal - Thanks for the perspective, I just needed to look at it through a different pair of glasses :)